# merge 3 files with awk in linux

Tags: awk

following problem: (similar to one last question)
I tried `

```
 awk 'FNR==NR {a[NR]=$0;next} {print a[1]","c[1]", "$0}' file1 file2 file3
```

but does not work

FILE1:

```
line1
line2
line3
```

and FILE2:

```
date1
```

and FILE3:

```
TITEL1
```

Result should be date1 merged to each line of file1.
So result:

```
line1, date1, TITEL1
line2, date1, TITEL1
line3, date1, TITEL1
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***Input***

```
[akshay@localhost tmp]$ cat f1
line1
line2
line3

[akshay@localhost tmp]$ cat f2
date1

[akshay@localhost tmp]$ cat f3
TITEL1
```

**Output**

```
[akshay@localhost tmp]$ awk 'FNR==1{i++}i<3{A[i,1]=$0;next}{print $0,A[1,1],A[2,1]}' OFS=', ' f2 f3 f1
line1, date1, TITEL1
line2, date1, TITEL1
line3, date1, TITEL1
```

Comment: No need for the 1s `awk 'FNR==1{i++}i<3{A[i]=$0;next}{print $0,A[1],A[2]}' OFS=', '`